# Encoding.UTF32.GetString equivalent to Java

Tags: java, c#

What's the java equivalent for

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList();

XXX Do some magic with arrayList. . .     

return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(arrayList.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.Byte")) as byte[]);
```

from c# in java? I'm trying to encode a decrypted byte array via RSA decryption.

The way i'm approaching it is,

```
new String(retBal, Charset.forName("UTF-32"));
```

Where retBal is my byte[] array. It doesn't feel and look right. My return string comes out as

```
��������������������
```

Comment: What is `arrayList`? I ask, because the .NET [`List<T>.ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) does not take a parameter.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add that part. Its just a basic ArrayList() in c#. Ill edit my post now

Comment: Not too familiar with Java, but after a quick search, your code looks correct. It may  be something to do with endianness. Try `UTF_32LE` or `UTF_32BE`.

Comment: As an aside, it's typically a better idea to use `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList` in C#. In any case, you can also simplify your code to be `arrayList.ToArray(typeof(byte))` instead of using reflection to fetch the type. If your original `arrayList` was defined `var arrayList = new List<byte>()`, you could simplify it further with simply `arrayList.ToArray()`

Comment: YAS! it was LE worked. Guess i missed it out when i was reading the documentation for .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for the .NET [`Encoding.UTF32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf32(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Gets an encoding for the UTF-32 format using the **little endian byte order**.

In Java, character set `UTF-32` is **big endian** by default (if no [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is present).

To force little endian byte order, use `UTF-32LE`.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! I guess i missed the LE portion on the documentation i read.